# Visual Studio Code: Powershell Greenhorn

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

My Code:

```
$a = $env:Path
$b = $a.Split(";")
Write-host $b
$a
$b
```

The automatic Help in Powershell advises me to
**Surround with Enum, funtion** ....

What am I advised to do ?
An explanation, some sample code could help

[image]

Thx in advance

Comment: It is not advising you to do anything.  When you select a block of code it gives you those options as a convenient way to do those things if you wish with your selection.

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious from your screenshot, but the crucial aspect is that **you've *selected* `$b[3]`**.

**Whenever you select a multi-character range**, Visual Studio's [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) **offers you *potentially useful actions***, indicated by and accessible via the *lightbulb icon*:

- You can click on the icon or use <kbd>Control-.</kbd> (period) to invoke the menu of available actions.
- Actions of a *general* nature that are *always* presented pertain to *surrounding* (enclosing) the selected text with various constructs, such as shown in your screenshot.

  - This is a convenient way to make the selected text part of a larger language construct, such as an `if` statement or a `function` definition.
  - These actions are *not prescriptive*, i.e. **it is up to you to decide whether any of the actions presented make sense** in the context of what you're trying to do.